# C Macro Whitespace

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am unable to accomplish the following because whitespaces are ignored(?) in the preprocessor. I understand that this is part of the standard, but I'm wondering if there's a work around using variadic or some indirect macro trick.

Variable:

```
#define DECL_INT(name) int #name

DECLR_INT(myValue);
// Expected: int myValue;
// Actual: intmyValue;
```

Structure:

```
#define ADD_CUSTOM_MEMBERS() \
   C_MEM(IntMember, int) \
   C_MEM(CharMember, char)

#define C_MEM(name, type) type #name;

typedef struct {
   int Stuff;

   ADD_CUSTOM_MEMBERS()
   // Expected: int IntMember;
   //           char CharMember;
} my_struct_t;
```

The goal is to have a generic structure that then each application can add its own members to it, natively.

There is a lot of information out there on white-spaces and macros, but I haven't seen anyone directly address this issue. I've seen plenty of examples where a prefix is added.

```
#define DECL_INT(name) int myPrefix_#name

DECLR_INT(myValue);
// Actual: int myPrefix_myValue;
```

Doing it this way keeps the whitespace between `int` and `myValue`, but I don't want a prefix.

And assuming adding a prefix is the only way of achieving this, I can't use this trick to declare a variable with the type as one of the arguments of the macro.

Comment: Why do you have `#` before `name` in the macro? That's used for turning the parameter into a string, but that makes no sense in an `int` declaration. The result should be `int "myValue";`, not `intmyValue;`

Comment: Even if the whitespace was respected, what do you expect `int "string literal"` to accomplish?

Comment: I think you're confusing the `#` stringizing operator with `##` token-pasting.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I missed that crucial part. I was trying to put `int myValue`. So no stringizing operator is required. Token-pasting will put two arguments together, but not convert them to string-literals?

Comment: Is there a way to put a whitespace before a string-literal? Say I am using a `#` to get the name of the argument as a string.

Comment: The trouble with first learning how to use a hammer is that EVERYTHING begins to look like a name. If you want to be unpopular, make your code cryptic with convoluted macros. Otherwise, simply use a nested struct for the "common" portions of each custom struct. Stay away from the dark side, Luke!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an erroneus `#`. Without it:

```
#define ADD_CUSTOM_MEMBERS() \
   C_MEM(IntMember, int) \
   C_MEM(CharMember, char)

#define C_MEM(name, type) type name;

typedef struct {
   int Stuff;

   ADD_CUSTOM_MEMBERS()
   // Expected: int IntMember;
   //           char CharMember;
} my_struct_t;
```

outputs with `gcc -E`:

```
typedef struct {
   int Stuff;

   int IntMember; char CharMember;

} my_struct_t;
```